# How can I display a Chart.js plugin-generated antenna on top of a bar chart without it overlapping?

Tags: javascript, typescript, canvas, chart.js

I have created a Chart.js plugin to draw a small antenna on top of each bar in the chart, however the antenna is overlapping with the bar. Is there any way to ensure that the antenna is displayed over the bar, so it won't be obscured?

```
    const topAntenna = {
      id: 'topAntenna',
      order: 4,
      beforeDraw(chart, args, options) {
        const { ctx, config, scales: { x, y } } = chart;
        ctx.save();
        ctx.strokeStyle = 'red';
        var data = chart.data.datasets[0].data;
        if (data.length > 0) {
          debugger
          //ctx.strokeRect(x, y, width, height)
          ctx.fillRect(x.getPixelForValue(0), y.getPixelForValue(data[0][1]) - 20, 10, 60);
        }
        ctx.restore();
      }
    }
```

Current output:

[image]

Expected output :

[image]

Comment: Change it to `afterDraw` if you want the antenna to be drawn after the bar